# Google Maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to display Google Map in my android app
I  followed the tutorial on android.com for this, obtaining MAP API keys & all.

Now the problem is : earlier it was working fine and maps were displayed properly but now since a few days, We cannt see the map. When it launches it shows the markers over it but the background is blank, only the boxes are appearing. Can someone please tell what's happening .

Thanks.

Comment: you don't have a real question here. the MAP key is for a specific environment. please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

- You have the wrong Maps API key for your signing key, or
- The device or emulator does not have Internet access, or
- You got rid of the `INTERNET` permission, or
- Something else is blocking your app's access to the Maps servers (e.g., firewall)

Comment: Thanks a lot . It was the Maps API key issue. Actually I shifted my project to a diff system and I guess this is where it went wrong. Anyway I generated fresh keys and it's working fine